# How to Rewrite URL(hiding id of an record)

Tags: .htaccess

I wonder if i could change my URL from `localhost/myproject/subject/1/ab-cd/tests` into `localhost/myproject/subject/ab-cd/tests` (**loss of id "1"**). I want to hide the ID. Could it be done by using `.htaccess`?

Any helps will be appreciated.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: How do you intend to identify record 1, if it is not in the URL?

Comment: Why do you want to hide id?

Comment: I know but i think the URL without id is more beautiful, so i ask if there is a way to hide it without causing any trouble in retrieving that ID.

Answer (score -1):

the question is not very clear enough to answer it properly. If id is being sent as GET request than it must be in the url....but you can still hide it:

- by encryptring it in url
- using sessions
- by using AJAX

Hope so it helps

Comment: It's generally best to avoid scattershot answers that have to guess at multiple ways the OP might want their question solved; instead, wait until the question is clearly phrased before answering. (Often, this will save you time on a question that later is closed.)

Comment: yup but still you can suggest OP some ideas though and make sure you dont down vote any answers so quickly. if you don't want to answer yourself dont down vote others answers Nathan Tuggy

Comment: For that, comments are the intended tool, and 50 rep is much closer than you might think. (Re: downvoting; most downvotes are, and should be, from those who have no particular desire or perhaps even ability to answer the question fully, only the ability to accurately judge at least some aspect of the answer as being un-useful, such as, perhaps, attempting to answer a question that can't be answered well.)

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiastic help, Manjeet Singh